# Naming an object that is an attribute of another object with the same getter/setter as Object Type

Tags: c#, class, naming-conventions

This is a fundamental question. When using objects as an attribute for an object, So Object2 has an attribute Object1.

Can you use the Object name as the type and name for the getter and setter or the second object.

```
Class Object1{}

Class Object2
{
    Object1 Object1 {get; set;}
    // OR
    Object1 Object1_{get; set;}
}
```

As I've tried it using the same name for simple programs and it works (though I've not dare to venture into complex code with it). I understand that there could be ambiguity, but will this actually work for any project?

Comment: Seems like it should since you have to qualify with the object of class2 type to get to the field. if class1 is nested, or has static methods, that might cause problems if the methods have the same name.

Comment: there is no problem with that, .Net it self does the same thing : the dialoge result attribute of Form class is named as it's type, and you will find it in many other attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.  In fact this is a very common pattern in C#

```
class Foo
{
   Bar Bar {get; set; }
}
```