# Primary Key Violation in Multi-threading EF6

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, ef-code-first, primary-key

I am working on a C# console application that downloads data from the Guild Wars 2 API and inputs it into my database with Entity Framework 6. I'm trying to use multi-threading so that I can speed up the process of inputting large amounts of data into my database.

The problem is when the code runs into my `DBContext.SaveChanges()` call in my `AddRecipes` method, the following error was returned:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Items'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Items'. The duplicate key value is (0).

Here is the portion of code that is related to my issue:

```
class Program
{
    private static ManualResetEvent resetEvent;
    private static int nIncompleteThreads = 0;

    //Call this function to add to the dbo.Items table
    private static void AddItems(object response)
    {
        string strResponse = (string)response;

        using (GWDBContext ctx = new GWDBContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Items> itemResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Items>>(strResponse);

            ctx.Items.AddRange(itemResponse);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }

        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref nIncompleteThreads) == 0)
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    //Call this function to add to the dbo.Recipes table
    private static void AddRecipes(object response)
    {
        string strResponse = (string)response;

        using (GWDBContext ctx = new GWDBContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<Recipes> recipeResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Recipes>>(strResponse);

            ctx.Recipes.AddRange(recipeResponse);

            foreach(Recipes recipe in recipeResponse)
            {
                ctx.Ingredients.AddRange(recipe.ingredients);
            }
            ctx.SaveChanges(); //This is where the error is thrown
        }

        if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref nIncompleteThreads) == 0)
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    static void GetResponse(string strLink, string type)
    {
        //This method calls the GW2 API through HTTPWebRequest
        //and store the responses in a List<string> responseList variable.
        GWHelper.GetAllResponses(strLink);

        resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        nIncompleteThreads = GWHelper.responseList.Count();

        //ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem creates threads for multi-threading
        switch (type)
        {
            case "I":
                {
                    foreach (string strResponse in GWHelper.responseList)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(AddItems), strResponse);
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case "R":
                {
                    foreach (string strResponse in GWHelper.responseList)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(AddRecipes), strResponse);
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }

        //Waiting then resetting event and clearing the responseList
        resetEvent.WaitOne();           
        GWHelper.responseList.Clear();
        resetEvent.Dispose();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strItemsLink = "items";
        string strRecipesLink = "recipes";

        GetResponse(strItemsLink, "I");
        GetResponse(strRecipesLink, "R");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Here is my DBContext class:

```
public class GWDBContext : DbContext
{
    public GWDBContext() : base("name=XenoGWDBConnectionString") { }

    public DbSet<Items> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Recipes> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }
}
```

Here is also my table classes (I know the names are confusing, I'm working on re-writing them):

```
public class Items
{
    public Items()
    {
        Recipes = new HashSet<Recipes>();
        Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] //This attribute makes sure that the id column is not an identity column since the api is sending that).
    public int id { get; set; }

    .../...
    public virtual ICollection<Recipes> Recipes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Recipes
{
    public Recipes()
    {
        disciplines = new List<string>();
        ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] //This attribute makes sure that the id column is not an identity column since the api is sending that).
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Items")] //This attribute points the output_item_id column to the Items table.

    .../...
    private List<string> _disciplines { get; set; }
    public List<string> disciplines
    {
        get { return _disciplines; }
        set { _disciplines = value; }
    }

    [Required]
    public string DisciplineAsString
    {
        //get; set;
        get { return string.Join(",", _disciplines); }
        set { _disciplines = value.Split(',').ToList(); }
    }

    public string chat_link { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> ingredients { get; set; }
    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public Ingredient()
    {
        Recipe = new HashSet<Recipes>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ingredientID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Items")] //This attribute points the item_id column to the Items table.
    public int item_id { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Recipes> Recipe { get; set; }
    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
}
```

Here are links that explains what is returned for the Items/Recipes class:

[Items](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/items)

[Recipes](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/recipes)

I noticed that after removing the foreign key constraints and the `public virtual Items Items { get; set; }` code the data will be saved correctly. I believe my error have something to do with having `public virtual Items Items` in the Recipes class. But from my understanding I needed to have that virtual variable in the class so Entity Framework can know the relationship between the classes. So why would having that virtual variable in my class cause the primary key violation to be thrown?

Comment: It is saying that you have duplicated ID of 0. This suggests you aren't actually setting the ID. Are you sure that you are definitely getting an id field and that it is being correctly deserialised into your object?

Comment: There were 0 Items when I checked at the error line. The Recipes are being deserialized correctly and the Items have been inserted correctly before the AddRecipes call.

Comment: Are the items that are on the Recipes also correct? Just wondering if you might have got some Items there with 0 ids or something...

Comment: The recipes are correct. The error is saying that I'm inserting a 0 id to the Items table even though I'm inserting to the Recipes table.

Comment: Is there a reason you set `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` on you primary key fields? If you do that, then you need to generate your own value. I suggest removing it and trying again.

Comment: The reason why it's set is because the GW2 API returns an id and they aren't in order. I will remove it and try again.

Comment: Then it's returning duplicate values, can you check that?

Comment: I removed that 'DatabaseGeneratedOption.None' option and it works. But now the id is not the same as the GW2 API. Is there a way around that? If not then I might need to make 2 id column.

Comment: Well provided the API is giving you unique data then you can leave it as before. What does the GW data look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149914/discussion-between-john-odom-and-davidg).

Comment: There's quite some mismatch between the classes and the linked json objects.

Comment: I know the json returns more data than what my class have but I think the problem have something to do with 'public virtual Items Items'. Once I removed that when removing the foreign key constraints everything started working.

Comment: I think it's simply caused by re-inserting existing `Items` objects when you insert the ingredients, but I'd have to see the exact content of `recipeResponse` to be able to verify that.

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need the list of items in a recipe. If you need to search which recipes have a particular item, you can do that by searching on the foreign key of Recipe (the primary key of Item).

There is a fundamental naming flaw with the code. You have a class Recipes and then a List of Recipes called Recipes. The same with Items.

You then have a foreign key  `[ForeignKey("Items")]` for Recipes. Which Items is this? The List or the Object Items. It's so prone to errors.

Rename your classes to `Recipe` and `Item`

```
public class Recipe
{ 
    public Recipe()


public class Item
{
    public Item()
```

Also - with the duplicate `Id` of `0`, as mentioned in the comments, it sounds like the `Id` is not being set.

Looking at the link to Recipes:

```
{
    .../...
    "ingredients": [
            { "item_id": 19684, "count": 50 },
            { "item_id": 19721, "count": 1 },
            { "item_id": 46747, "count": 10 }
    ],
    "id": 7319,
    .../...
}
```

Recipe should not contain a list of items, but a list of ingredients. The class structure should be:

```
Recipe has:
public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

Ingredient has:
public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

The `Item` class doesn't have a list of Ingredients or Recipes, these list are retrieved by querying the database Items on the Ingredient with the  foreign key matching the primary key for the Item, or the database Ingredients on the Recipe foreign key matching the primary key of the Ingredient - you can then do a join to find any items of those Ingredients.

So make the following changes:

There doesn't need to be a mention of Recipe or Ingredients in the Item class.

```
public Item() // remove pluralisation
{
    // Remove these from the constructor,
    // Recipes = new HashSet<Recipes>();
    // Ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
}

// remove these from the class.
// public virtual ICollection<Recipes> Recipes { get; set; }
// public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
```

**An Ingredient has many Items - ergo a collection of  Items**

```
public Ingredient()
{
    // You don't need a collection of Recipes - 
    // you need a collection of Items.
    // Recipe = new HashSet<Recipes>();
}
.../...
[ForeignKey("Item")] // change this
public Item Item // include an Item object - the PK of the
    // Item is the FK of the Ingredient


.../...
// Remove Recipes
// public virtual ICollection<Recipes> Recipe { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

I prefer [using the object name for the variable Item Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071498/naming-an-object-that-is-an-attribute-of-another-object-with-the-same-getter-set).

**A Recipe has many Ingredients - ergo a collection of Ingredients**

```
public Recipes()
{
    disciplines = new List<string>();
    ingredients = new HashSet<Ingredient>();
}
.../...
// [ForeignKey("Items")] remove this
[ForeignKey("Ingredient")] 
public Ingredient Ingredient // include as Ingredient object 
    // the PK of the Ingredient is the FK for the Recipe

.../...
public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
// The Recipe does not have an Item, the Ingredient has 
// has a collection of <Item> Items
// public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
```

Also I'm not sure why you are using Hashsets. I'd make them into Lists if you have no particular reason for using them.

If this doesn't fix your code, I'll review the remainder of it.